# \n after a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hey I wrote the following code for an assigment:

```
def triangular_area():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        print(((i+1)**2)/2, end=" ")
```

and it prints the following:

```
0.5 2.0 4.5 8.0 12.5 18.0 24.5 32.0 40.5 50.0
```

however, If I call another function that prints a random string right after I call triangular_area, it prints the string in the same line like that:

```
0.5 2.0 4.5 8.0 12.5 18.0 24.5 32.0 40.5 50.0 "random str"
```

how can I insert a single \n that will occur in the end of for statment?

the machine should read: 0.5 2.0 4.5 8.0 12.5 18.0 24.5 32.0 40.5 50.0\n

thank

Comment: Print a new line character after calling triangular_area()

Answer (score 3):

Calling print without parameter will just add a newline by default:

```
def triangular_area():
    for i in range(0, 10): 
        print(((i+1)**2)/2, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: thanks I  just tried it but the submission algorithm gives me this:

https://prnt.sc/myiplq

Comment: @trizz use `def triangular_area():
    print(" ".join((str(((i+1)**2)/2)  for i in range(0, 10))))`

Comment: did you use ```end=" "``` in the loop?

Comment: @eyllanesc could you explain syntax wise why it prints everything in one line? 
I get the usage of " ".join for each "i" but why does it do everything on a single line?